# Can not create grunt with timeRestrictionIcal using tapkey API

Tags: tapkey

Can not create grunt with timeRestrictionIcal, get TimeRestrictionIcalMalformed error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Parameters:

```
{
  "boundLockId": "string",
  "contactId": "string",
  "timeRestrictionIcal":"string"
}
```

Where timeRestrictionIcal is

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:http://localhost:3000
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20230422T030000Z62505530-4988-4a93-acff-1f673e50bf76
DTSTAMP:20230422T030000Z
DTSTART; TZID=Europe/Uzhgorod:20230425T030000
DTEND; TZID=Europe/Uzhgorod:20230425T130000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

How to create tapkey grunt with timeRestrictionIcal param?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem are causing unecessary whitespaces

- After every `\n`  there is an unecessary space
- After `DTSTART;`  and `DTEND;`  there is unecessary space as well

Once you get rid of them that request goes through successfully.

Result ICAL:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:http://localhost:3000\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:20230422T030000Z62505530-4988-4a93-acff-1f673e50bf76\nDTSTAMP:20230422T030000Z\nDTSTART;TZID=Europe/Uzhgorod:20230425T030000\nDTEND;TZID=Europe/Uzhgorod:20230425T130000\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR
```